# ¿Color de caja de boxplot cambia luego de usar a función legend?

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

Hace buen tiempo no usaba R base para hacer gráficos, pero el día de hoy quise hacer un boxplot.

```
set.seed(2021)
x<-c(sample(1:100,50,T),sample(200:400,7,T))

# El gráfico.
boxplot(x, col = "orange", frame.plot=F)
legend("topright",legend = paste0("% de Outliers = ",
                                  round(length(boxplot(x)$out)*100/length(x),2),"%"),
       cex=.8,inset=.02, fill = "orange")
```

Pero curiosamente el resultado es que la caja del boxplot es de color gris. Al parecer al aplicar la legenda se cambió del color "orange" a "gray". No sé por qué sucede esto. Antes colocar la legenda no implicaba que cambiara el color de la caja.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A que se puede deber, es una actualización de R? Es un problema con mi instalación de R?
En el caso que sea una actualización como puedo hacer para que el color de la caja se mantenga de color "orange".

Psdta: Uso R 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que cada vez que invocas `boxplot()` se dispara el efecto colateral, es decir la gráfica, y en tu código lo estás haciendo dos veces, la primera con el color adecuado:

```
boxplot(x, col = "orange", frame.plot=F)
```

Y la segunda, esta vez sin color, cuando recuperas los "outliers":

```
boxplot(x)$out
```

Lo que puedes hacer eventualmente, es salvar la gráfica en una variable para que desde esta puedas obtener los datos para la leyenda:

```
set.seed(2021)
x<-c(sample(1:100,50,T),sample(200:400,7,T))

plt <- boxplot(x, col = "orange", frame.plot=F)
legend("topright",legend = paste0("% de Outliers = ",
                                  round(length(plt$out)*100/length(x),2),"%"),
       cex=.8,inset=.02, fill = "orange")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio.